# Websphere MQ 7.0 COA reply going to dead letter queue

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I'm sending a message from a queue manager called "AVSR.TEST". I've got a local queue configured called "ReplyQueue". I'm trying to get a COA back to this "ReplyQueue" from another queue manager called "TEST".

Here's my setup:
QM1: AVSR.TEST,
local q: ReplyQueue,
remote q: TEST.REMOTE (defined correctly to connect to QM TEST)

QM2: TEST,
local q: TEST.LOCAL,
remote q: ReplyQueue (defined as: remote queue=ReplyQueue, remote queue manager=AVSR.TEST, transmission queue=TEST.TRX)

I've got a java app that collects a message from a socket and puts it to TEST.REMOTE
in the code, where I build my message, I've added:

```
myMessageIn.replyToQueueManagerName = "AVSR.TEST";
myMessageIn.replyToQueueName = "ReplyQueue";
myMessageIn.report = MQC.MQRO_COA_WITH_DATA;
```

I've tried with or without setting "myMessageIn.userId".

my COA ends up in the dead letter queue on QM "TEST" with reason "unknown remote queue manager". Looking at the dead letter header it contains:

```
destination queue: ReplyQueue
destination QM: AVSR.TEST
etc...
Put application type: Queue manager
put application name: TEST
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this. I was putting my originating QM name into the variable instead of the destination QM name where the reply will come from. Working now.